# Diamond printing in C with a positive odd value less than 20 entered by user

Tags: c, for-loop

So I have updated my program so far , and have added in the conditions, the if does not seem to catch them I am not sure why , I have been playing around with placement of it  and cannot seem to get it to work , this is what I have changed it too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

int main (void ) 
{

```
int number; 

printf("Enter a positive odd number less than 20:"); 
scanf("%d",&number); 
//check for conditions 

if (number %2 == 0 && number > 20 && number <0){

    printf ("Please re-enter a positive odd number less than 20:"); 
    scanf ("%d", &number);
}

else 
{   
    // top of the diamond 
    for (int i=1; i<number;i +=2) 
{

    for (int j=0; j<number-1 -i/2 ; j++) 
    {

        printf(" "); 
    }
    for (int j=0; j<i;j++){

        printf("*"); 
    }

    printf("\n"); 
}

//bottom of the diamond 
for (int i =number;i>0;i-=2)
{

    for (int j =0; j<number -1 -i/2; j++)
    {
        printf(" "); 
    }
    for (int j=0; j<i;j++) 
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}       
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: These sort of questions should be addressed to your professor or TA.

Comment: I have emailed my professor , and have not gotten a response back , thought I could also find help on here as well

Answer (score 0):

1. The `scanf("%d",number);` is not correct. You should give the address of the integer to `%d`. Like this .. `scanf("%d",&number);`
2. To verify whether the number is odd or less than 20 you can add conditions to check this.

   ```
   if (number%2 == 0)
   {
       printf(" ....");
   }
   else if (number >20)
   {
      printf("....");
   }
   else
   {
       // rest of code to print diamond
   }
   ```
3. You can also add a loop to retry the scanf until the user enters correct number. I will leave that as an exercise to you.

Comment: Don't forget to test the return value from `scanf()` (as well as the value that's set in `number`).  If it isn't `1`, all bets are off; the input failed.

Comment: That's always a good Idea. I did not want to confuse the OP by adding too many details

Comment: thank you for the scanf catch , I will add the conditions in , but can someone explain why the nested for loops make a diamond? and why there needs to be two for top and bottom ?

Comment: Take a specific value of `number` e.g. 6 and check what is printed in each loop. Basically, the First outer loop prints the top half of the diamond, and the second outer loop prints the bottom half.

Answer (score 0):

This prints a nice simple diamond:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 5;
    char star[2*height];
    memset(star,'*',2*height);

    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)    printf("%*.*s\n", height+i, 2*i+1, star);
    for(int i=height-2; i>=0; --i) printf("%*.*s\n", height+i, 2*i+1, star);

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```